# R: looped variable assignment, augmenting variable calculation each time

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, variable-assignment

I am trying to calculate a regression variable based on a range of variables in my data set. I would like the regression variable (ei: Threshold 1) to be calculated using a different variable set in each iteration of running the regression.

Aim to collected SSR values for each threshold range, and thus identify the ideal threshold based on the data.

Data (df) variables: Yield, Prec, Price, 0C, 1C, 2C, 3C, 4C, 5C, 6C, 7C, 8C, 9C, 10C

Each loop calculates "thresholds" by selecting a different "b" each time.

```
a <- df$0C
b <- df$1C

Threshold1 <- (a-b)

Threshold2 <- (b)
```

Where "b" would be changing in each loop, ranging from 1C to 9C.

Each individual threshold set (1 and 2) should be used to run a regression, and save the SSR for comparison with the subsequent regression utilizing thresholds based on a new "b" value (ranging from 1C TO 9C)

Regression:

```
reg <- lm(log(Yield)~Threshold1+Threshold2+log(Price)+prec+I(prec^2),data=df)
```

for each loop of the Regression, I vary the components of calculating thresholds in the following manner:

Current approach is centered around the following code:

```
 df <- read.csv("Data.csv",header=TRUE)

 names(df)
 0C-9Cvarlist <- names(df)[9:19]
 ssr.vec <- matrix(,21,1)

 for(i in 1:length(varlist)){

 a <- df$0C
 b <- df$[i]

 Threshold1 <- (a-b)

 Threshold2 <- (b)

 reg <- lm(log(Yield)~Threshold1+Threshold2+log(Price)+prec+I(prec^2),data=df)

 r2 <- summary(reg)$r.squared

 ssr.vec[i,] <- c(varlist,r2)
 }

 colnames(ssr.vec) <- c("varlist","r2")
```

I am failing to achieve the desired result with the above approach.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can spot quite a few mistakes...

You need to add variables of interest (Threshold1 anf Threshold2) to the data in the regression. Also, I think that you need to select varlist[i] and not varlist to create your ssr.vec. You need 2 columns to your ssr.vec which is a matrix, so you should call it matrix. You also cannot use something like df$[i] to extract a column! Why is the matrix of length 21 ?! Change the column name to C0,..,C9 and not 0C,..,9C.

For future reference, solve the simple errors before asking question... and include error messages in your post!

This should do the job:

```
df <- read.csv("Data.csv",header=TRUE)

names(df)[8:19] = paste0("C",0:10)
varlist <- names(df)[9:19]
ssr.vec <- matrix(,21,2)

for(i in 1:length(varlist)){

    a <- df$C0
    b <- df[,i+9]

    df$Threshold1 <- (a-b)

    df$Threshold2 <- (b)

    reg <- lm(log(Yield)~Threshold1+Threshold2+log(Price)+prec+I(prec^2),data=df)

    r2 <- summary(reg)$r.squared

    ssr.vec[i,] <- c(varlist[i],r2)
}

colnames(ssr.vec) <- c("varlist","r2")
```

Comment: thank you, this is very helpful. Also I will take care in improving any future questions. Very much appreciated